# Trying to solve sum binomial expression

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

I need help to explore the following equalities. In particular I don't get how the second and the third expressions are obtained starting from the first. I've tried to write the terms of the summation, to collect terms and so on but nothing worked. Here the problem:

SECOND EQUALITY SOLVED

$$\displaystyle\sum_{m=M_{jk}}^j {j\choose m} a_j^{m-1}(1-a_j)^{j-m-1}(m-a_jj) \big|_{a_j = 0} = 
{j\choose M_{jk}}(1-a_j)^{j-M_{jk}}a_j^{M_{jk}-1}M_{jk}\big|_{a_j = 0} = j I_{\{\gamma_{jk} \leq w_j\}}$$
$M_{jk} = \left \lceil{\frac{\gamma_{jk}}{w_j}}\right \rceil$, $\gamma_{jk}$ and $w_j$ real positive numbers 
$a_j\in [0,1] $
$I$ the indicator function

Comment: Do you mean by $\big | _{a_j=0}$ that the expression should be evaluated at $a_j=0$? In that case almost everything vanishes, no?

Comment: @Milten Yes I mean that, but is not always true that everything vanishes. Indeed, for instance, if the exponent of $a_j$ is 0, which is possible, then the term is just one. My problem is how the first equality is reached, before evaluating at zero the expression. I solved the second equality :).

Comment: Great! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first equality isn't actually complicated at all. The right side is just the first term of the sum, i.e. with $m=M_{jk}$. For some reason, they chose to evaluate the last factor $(M_{jk}-a_j j)|_{a_j=0} = M_{jk}$. They also wrote $(1-a_j)^{j-M_{jk}}$ instead of $(1-a_j)^{j-M_{jk}-1}$ (probably a typo... but never mind that, since it evaluates to $1$ anyways).

So this is the point: If $m>1$, then $a_j^m = 0$, so the term vanishes. And the only way for $m=1$ to be possible is if $m=M_{jk}=1$, so whatever $M_{jk}$ might be, we only need to look at the first term. Note that $M_{jk}\ge 1$ always.

That said, I think it could have been written in a more consistent or clearer way by the authors...

EDIT: Maybe a point of confusion for you is that they definitely use $a_j=0$ already in the first equality. They just only use on some of the terms.

Comment: Mmmm I'm not sure why they considered just the first term of the sum. And also the typo I don't know... it's from a scientific paper I don't think a typo is probable to happen. I think they developed the terms of the sum in some way. Btw you too can be correct... thank you

Comment: It seems you are right! After plugging in some values, I see the equality holds for any $a_j$ (and there was no typo). I'll try to prove it for general $a_j$ later... maybe it collapses into a telescoping sum of some sort. Well, the case $a_j=0$ still follows from what I wrote ;)